# mongodb group by on C API

Tags: mongodb, group-by, database

I have a data. Let me show you the example of that

1
1
2
2
2
3

And, I'd like to get the number of each values using Group by. The result will be like below

value | count
1     |  2
2     |  3
3     |  1

Maybe, the group by query on Mongo Shell is like this

```
db.collection.group(
{ key : {value:true},
reduce: function(obj, prev) { prev.csum += 1; },
initial: { csum: 0 }
})
```

But, I have to convert that query to C code with mongoDB C API. 
I tried to make some code using bson_append_bson like that.. but, failed..

What shoould I do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I setup a Mongo 2.2.1 instance on my machine on port 12345.  I created a `test.data` collection and populated it with

```
use test
db.data.insert({value:1})
db.data.insert({value:1})
db.data.insert({value:2})
db.data.insert({value:2})
db.data.insert({value:2})
db.data.insert({value:3})
```

per your sample data.  Using the [latest driver](https://github.com/mongodb/mongo-c-driver/tree/v0.6), I wrote the following sample code.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <mongo.h>

int main( char *argv[] ) {
    bson b, out;
    mongo conn;

    if( mongo_connect( &conn, "127.0.0.1", 12345 ) != MONGO_OK ) {
        switch( conn.err ) {
            case MONGO_CONN_NO_SOCKET:
                printf( "FAIL: Could not create a socket!\n" );
                break;
            case MONGO_CONN_FAIL:
                printf( "FAIL: Could not connect to mongod. Make sure it's listening at 127.0.0.1:27017.\n" );
                break;
            }

        exit( 1 );
    }

    bson_init( &b );
        bson_append_string( &b, "aggregate", "data" );
        bson_append_start_array( &b, "pipeline" );
            bson_append_start_object( &b, "0" );
                bson_append_start_object( &b, "$group" );
                    bson_append_string( &b, "_id", "$value" );
                    bson_append_start_object( &b, "count" );
                        bson_append_int( &b, "$sum", 1 );
                    bson_append_finish_object( &b );
                bson_append_finish_object( &b );
            bson_append_finish_object( &b );
        bson_append_finish_array( &b );
    bson_finish( &b );
    bson_print( &b );

    printf( "command result code: %d\n", mongo_run_command( &conn, "test", &b, &out ) );
    bson_print( &out );

    bson_destroy( &b );
    bson_destroy( &out );
    mongo_destroy( &conn );
    return( 0 );
}
```

Instead of the [`$group`](http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/Aggregation#Aggregation-Group) command, which doesn't work in sharded environments, I used the [Aggregation Framework](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/applications/aggregation/) (new since 2.1).  The above C code is the equivalent to

```
use test
db.data.aggregate({$group:{_id:"$value",count:{$sum:1}}})
```

in the Mongo shell.